# Is there a keyboard shortcut to open the list of networks?

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts, windows-8

In order for me to connect to my corporate VPN, I need to click the VPN link in the list of networks. This isn’t really a problem, just an inconvenience.

To open the list of networks in Windows 8 (from the desktop) you can click the network icon in the tray. To open from the Start menu you need the *Info Pane* (<kbd>Win</kbd>+<kbd>I</kbd>) and then click the network icon (at the bottom).

My goal is to go straight to the list of networks from any screen with a single keystroke. Does anyone know the **keyboard shortcut to open the list of networks**?

Comment: Why not create a shortcut to the VPN connection on your Desktop and assign it a global shortcut?

Comment: I like the idea, but looking for a keyboard shortcut - one I can take with me from machine to machine, too. I really find myself repeating this task everywhere I go.

Comment: Soooooooo needy. Apparently, you're too good to take 1 extra step. 48 new shortcuts in Windows 8 and it's still not good enough for you!

Comment: I do hope @Mufasa is being sarcastic.

Comment: @Ted: Yes, I was.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know any shortcut to open the network list, but you can access it via the command line:

```
rundll32.exe van.dll,RunVAN
```

Comment: Nice work. This is the one.

Answer (score 4):

<kbd>Win</kbd> + <kbd>B</kbd> gets you to the notification area.  You could either arrow key over to the icon, or set it as the first icon (from the left).

Then, all you have to do is: <kbd>Win</kbd> + <kbd>B</kbd>, <kbd>Enter</kbd>.

Comment: This is not true, unfortunately

Comment: Didn't work for me I'm afraid

Comment: +1 Win+b works for me on Windows 8.1, thanks! 'Show hidden icons' always gets focus first, but you can at least make the network icon the next one over by editing its behaviour in the customize dialog.

Comment: Almost there but still I couldn't use my up arrow(or another key?) to get to the network of choice.

Answer (score 2):

There is no built in way for the Windows but you can do it using [AutoHotKey](http://www.autohotkey.com), download it and install it. Now open the notepad and type the following code

> ^L::Run::{7007acc7-3202-11d1-aad2-00805fc1270e}

and save it with .ahk extension, launch this script by double click on it and now when you will click the <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>L</kbd> it will open the network connections window.

You can also compile this script after creating it by right click on it which would become a portable exe, just carry it wherever and launch it.

**Note**: You can change the `L` key with your preferred key.

Comment: You can tell me if you don't like this way.